# Halts for all rejects, but might accept/loop otherwise?

Tags: turing-machines, terminology, undecidability

If a Turing machine halts for all rejects of L but might accept/loop otherwise, how is L's recognizability classified?

| Recognizability | Decidability | ${\langle L\rangle}$ | ${\langle \overline{L}\rangle}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Turing-Unrecognizable | Undecidable | loop or reject | loop or reject |
| Turing-Recognizable | Undecidable | accept | reject or loop |
| Turing-Recognizable | Decidable | accept | reject |
| Co-Turing-Recognizable | Undecidable | reject or loop | accept |
| **Turing-???** | Undecidable | accept or loop | reject |
| **Co-Turing-???** | Undecidable | reject | accept or loop |

Comment: I take it that by "loop" you mean "does not terminate"? A machine may fail to terminate without "entering a loop".

Comment: *When starting a turing machine on an input, three outcomes are possible. The machine may accept, reject, or loop. By loop we mean.. never leading to a halting state* -- [Theory of Comp, Sipser](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Computatio/1aMKAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA170&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Loop means "not accept", i.e., reject. If it halts on all rejects, it halts on all inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question

> If a Turing machine halts for all rejects of L but might accept/loop otherwise, how is L's recognizability classified?

$L$ is Turing-unrecognizable, but $\overline{L}$ is Turing-recognizable.

To see this, let $L=\overline{A_{TM}}$ and $\overline{L}=A_{TM}$, where $A_{TM} = \{(M,w)|\space M \space \text{is a TM that accepts} \space w\}$.

We can create a TM $M_L$ for $L$ that simulates the execution of the input $M$ on $w$. This TM will always halt and rejects when $M$ accepts but it is not guaranteed to always halt when $M$ does not accept. This is still a valid TM but **not** a recognizer. In Sipser it was proven that $L$ is unrecognizable but $\overline{L} $ is recognizable.

I think your table is a little misleading since it somehow hides the possibility of $L$ or its complement being TM-recognizable but not TM-decidable. Or maybe you overlooked the possibility that there are TM that are not recognizers. I am not sure what is the proper term to be used for them, though.

Comment: So basically we don't need to distinguish between reject and loop for recognizability, both are considered a *fail to accept*. Updated my table, but with this clarification I see that my `accept/loop` cases are invalid.